# Python seems to randomly invert list items during long loop

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array of dictionaries of the form:

```
[
    {
        generic_key: specific_key,
        generic_value: specific_value
    }
    ...
]
```

I am trying to interpret this into an array of dictionaries of this form:

```
[
    {
        specific_key: specific_value
    }
    ...
]
```

I tried this:

```
new_array = []
for row in old_array:
    values = list(row.values())
    key = values[0]
    val = values[1]
    new_array.append({key: val})
```

This works in *most* cases, but in some, it swaps them around to form a dict like this:

```
{
    specific_value: specific_key
}
```

I've looked at the source file, and the rows in which it does this are identical to the rows in which it does not do this.

It's perhaps worth mentioning that the list in question is about 3000 elements in length.

Am I doing something stupid? I guess that maybe list(row.values()) does not necessarily preserve the order, but I don't see why it wouldn't.

EDIT fixed code typo suggesting that it was appending sets

Comment: `new_array.append({key, val})` is appending a `set` not a `dict`. You need to change the comma to a semi-colon

Comment: Did you mean to type: `new_array.append({key: val})`. Otherwise the code you have creates a list with some sets in it.

Comment: Ok, well now you're hitting up against dictionary ordering in older versions of Python. Rather than doing `values()` and then indexing that, why don't you access the values by key in each dict?

Comment: I'm using python 3.7.

Comment: Why the close votes?

Comment: You might be using 3.7, but are you sure the data was produced using something that respects order?

Comment: dictionary doesn't have to keep order - at least in older Pythons. You would have to use `collection.OrderedDict` to keep order or better use `row["generic_key"]` instead of `list()` and `values[0]`

Comment: I'm not sure that dictionary keep items ordered. Check this post, you may find something interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6/39980744.

Comment: @dome in 3.6 dictionary order is an implementation detail, and guaranteed in 3.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order in which `dict` keys/values are enumerated is ostensibly arbitrary (there's certainly a logic to it, and as of I think python3.7+, it's *consistent*, but while I don't know off the top of my head what the ordering criteria are) - if you wanted order, you would have used a `list` instead of a `dict` to store them in the first place. If `generic_key` and `generic_value` are the same each time, then the ideal way to handle this problem is to simply extract by key:

```
key = row['generic_key']
value = row['generic_value']
```

If this isn't the case but there is a consistent way to differentiate between `generic_key` and `generic_value`, then you can grab *both* the keys and values, and do that:

```
items = tuple(row.items())
if items[0][0] is the generic_key:  # insert whatever condition you need to here
    key = items[0][1]
    value = items[1][1]
else
    key = items[1][1]
    value = items[0][1]
```

Comment: Part 2 of this looks like the best way, thank you. I didn't create the original list of dicts myself, and this whole thing is to avoid me having to to manually edit a 3000 element list!

Comment: Just a quick note, in Python3.7, items[0][0] doesn't work: TypeError: 'dict_items' object does not support indexing

Comment: might need to do `list(row.items())` then, I guess. I forgot that `dict.items()` returns a generator instead of a full list/tuple.